# Laravel Cashier Paddle - unable to resolve the specified webhook URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, webhooks, laravel-cashier

I am trying to set up Laravel Cashier with Paddle ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cashier-paddle#creating-subscriptions)) but for some reason subscriptions are not being created in my database. I generate a pay link on the server and render it in the view, it sends me through the Paddle payment flow but after completing that no subscription is created.

I think Cashier is supposed to create the subscription after receiving the `subscription_created` webhook event, but I can't seem to connect Paddle and my application. Using the Paddle Webhook Simulator I get an error that Paddle "was unable to resolve the specified webhook URL".

[image: paddle sandbox unable to resolve the specified webhook URL]

I have my sandbox credentials stored in my **.env** variables:

```
PADDLE_VENDOR_ID=1234
PADDLE_VENDOR_AUTH_CODE=XXXXX
PADDLE_PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
XXXXXXXXXX
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
PADDLE_SANDBOX=true
```

Then generate the pay link for the user to click on:

```php
'monthlyPlanLink' => auth()->user()->newSubscription('monthly', $monthlyPlanId)
                ->returnTo(route('candidate.dashboard'))
                ->create()
```

I'm able to click through the Paddle UI and enter test card numbers, but after clicking pay no subscription is created. I defined the route explicitly in my **routes/web.php** folder and have updated `paddle/*` to be excluded from CSRF protection. This is the paddle webhook route:

```php
Route::post('/paddle/webhook', 'WebhookController')->name('webhook');
```

I'm unable to receive the webhook from Paddle and create a subscription row for a user. What am I doing wrong here and how can I create subscriptions for my users once they've entered their payment information?

I have `"laravel/cashier-paddle": "^1.4"` installed in **composer.json**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent a PR and updated the docs. For local development you need to use something like Ngrok or Expose to make your local development endpoints accessible to Paddle (and the rest of the world). Without that `.test` domains are only accessible on your own computer.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cashier-paddle#webhooks-local-development